# Add a new paragraph in Word which includes DOCPROPERTY fields using OpenXML in C#

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm writing a application that can edit paragraphs in a Word Template (.docx). In these paragraphs they can contain custom DOCPROPERTY. I can read and edit the paragraph then write them back successfully, however when I write them back when a DOCPROPERTY is included it writes it back as text.

An example of my code to edit a paragraph is as follows. I understand why this is happening in my code because I'm writing it as Text. my question is how I write DOCPROPERTY to a .docx file so Word reads it as DOCPROPERTY and not text.

```
     paragraph.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
     paragraph.AppendChild<Run>(new Run(new Text("DOCPROPERTY "System"  \* MERGEFORMAT")));
```

I've searched around and cannot see a suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to do it.

```
Run r = new Run();
Text t = new Text();

t.Text = "System";
r.Append(t);
r.Append(new Text { Text = " ", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
r.Append(new SimpleField() { Instruction = @"DOCPROPERTY  System  \\*MERGEFORMAT" });
paragraph.Append(r);
```